# Using Mongo query to find an in array element

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Have records in my db with such structure:

```
{ 
  "_id" : "YA14163134", 
  "discount" : "", 
  "retail" : "115.0000", 
  "cost" : "", 
  "description" : "Caterpillar Mens Big Twist Analog Watch", 
  "stock_update" : "05", 
  "brand" : "Kronos", 
  "img_url" : "image2342000.jpg", 
  "UPC" : "4895053708012", 
  "stock" : [ [ "1611292138", "5" ], [ "1612032232", "4" ], [ "1612050918", "0" ] ] 
}
```

and looking for query to get all records that have in "stock"  "1612050918" value. That is update id.

Trying something like:

```
db.vlc.find({stock: {$elemMatch:{$all:["1612050918"]}}})
```

or

```
db.vlc.find({stock: { $in : ['1611292138']}})
```

or

```
db.vlc.find({stock: { $all : [[1611292138]]}})
```

with no result. It works only if I include in request second array element like here

```
db.vlc.find({stock: { $all : [['1611292138', '7']]}})
```

but that limit my request to all items from update with qnty 7 when I need with any qnty. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

use this query:

```
{
    "stock" : {
        "$elemMatch" : {
            "$elemMatch" : {
                "$eq" : "1611292138"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Explanation:

- The first $elemMatch allows you to scan all three arrays under **stock**
- The nex $elemMatch allows you to scan the two elements in the sub-arrays
- since $elemMatch requires a query object, the $eq notation is used for a literal match.

If you know that "1611292138" will always be *the first* element of the sub-array, your query becomes simpler:

```
{ "stock" : { "$elemMatch" : { "0" : "1611292138" } } }
```

Explanation:

- Scan all arrays under **stock**
- Look for "1611292138" in the first slot of each sub-array

Comment: Thank you. Great explanation! Position is fixed so scanning 0 element is to my mind the best approach.Appreciate your help. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Use nested `$elemMatch`  as below :

```
db.vlc.find({stock: { "$elemMatch":{"$elemMatch":{"$all":["1612050918"]}}}})
```

Or

```
 db.vlc.find({stock: {"$elemMatch":{ "$elemMatch":{"$in" : ["1612050918"]}}}})
```

Comment: **[What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)**